# Adjustments to heatmap (geom_tile)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm very new to R and am trying to make a heatmap for a colleague of mine.

I've been able to generate a heatmap, but there are a few things wrong.

This is what my plot currently looks like:

[image: heatmap]

What I would like to change from my existing code:

- I would like to figure out someway to order the sample names in my table so they're grouped together. For example, for the sample `NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150`, I would like this to be grouped with all *IgG* samples.

In other words, I was thinking of something like this for ordering on the x and y axis, but not sure how to implement it:

```
    sample_order <-c(
"NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150",
"NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150",
"XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150",
"NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_p150",
"NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150",
"XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150"

    )
```

- I'm also trying to change the dynamic range of colors. Right now it's hard to see the difference between 20% and 50% on the plot. Is it possible to invert the colors as well?

My code:

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse); library(scales)

best_peak <- read_csv("/Users/kylestangline/OneDrive - Eclipse Bioinnovations Inc/Projects/20210427-eclip-adar005/overlaps/clusters/heatmap.csv")


best_peak %>%
  separate(`Peak Comparison`, into = c("peak1", "peak2"), sep = " vs ") %>%
  mutate(label = paste(percent(Rate, accuracy = 1), comma(Intersection.Value, accuracy = 1), sep = "\n")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(peak1, peak2, fill = Rate)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(aes(label = label), size = 1.50, color = "gray80", lineheight = 0.7) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

## Table

One extra thing about the table: my code grabs the sample names from the Peak Comparison column, where it is separated by " vs "

| Peak Comparison | Param -a | Param -b | Intersection.Value | Total -a | Total -b | Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 vs NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | 12770 | 12770 | 12770 | 1 |
| NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 vs NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_p150 | NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_p150 | 4370 | 12770 | 94156 | 0.342208301 |
| NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 vs NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | 2260 | 12770 | 10012 | 0.225729125 |
| NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 vs NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 | NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 | 4034 | 12770 | 81936 | 0.315896633 |
| NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 vs XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | 2352 | 12770 | 11470 | 0.20505667 |
| NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 vs XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 | NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 | 5358 | 12770 | 253054 | 0.419577134 |
| NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 vs NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | 2242 | 10012 | 12770 | 0.223931282 |
| NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 vs NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_p150 | NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_p150 | 3220 | 10012 | 94156 | 0.321614063 |
| NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 vs NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | 10012 | 10012 | 10012 | 1 |
| NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 vs NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 | NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 | 3046 | 10012 | 81936 | 0.304234918 |
| NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 vs XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | 1813 | 10012 | 11470 | 0.181082701 |
| NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 vs XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 | NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 | 3850 | 10012 | 253054 | 0.384538554 |
| XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 vs NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | 2276 | 11470 | 12770 | 0.198430689 |
| XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 vs NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_p150 | XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_p150 | 3463 | 11470 | 94156 | 0.301918047 |
| XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 vs NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | 1772 | 11470 | 10012 | 0.176987615 |
| XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 vs NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 | XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 | 3219 | 11470 | 81936 | 0.280645161 |
| XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 vs XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | 11470 | 11470 | 11470 | 1 |
| XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 vs XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 | XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 | 4439 | 11470 | 253054 | 0.38700959 |
| NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_p150 vs NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_p150 | NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | 4668 | 94156 | 12770 | 0.365544244 |
| NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_p150 vs NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_p150 | NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_p150 | NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_p150 | 94156 | 94156 | 94156 | 1 |
| NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_p150 vs NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_p150 | NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | 3362 | 94156 | 10012 | 0.335797044 |
| NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_p150 vs NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 | NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_p150 | NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 | 16636 | 94156 | 81936 | 0.203036516 |
| NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_p150 vs XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_p150 | XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | 3714 | 94156 | 11470 | 0.323801221 |
| NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_p150 vs XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 | NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_p150 | XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 | 28631 | 94156 | 253054 | 0.304080462 |
| NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 vs NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 | NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | 4273 | 81936 | 12770 | 0.334612373 |
| NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 vs NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_p150 | NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 | NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_p150 | 16572 | 81936 | 94156 | 0.202255419 |
| NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 vs NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 | NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | 3154 | 81936 | 10012 | 0.315021974 |
| NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 vs NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 | NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 | NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 | 81936 | 81936 | 81936 | 1 |
| NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 vs XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 | XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | 3438 | 81936 | 11470 | 0.299738448 |
| NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 vs XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 | NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 | XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 | 26501 | 81936 | 253054 | 0.323435364 |
| XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 vs NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 | NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | 5899 | 253054 | 12770 | 0.461942052 |
| XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 vs NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_p150 | XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 | NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_p150 | 30344 | 253054 | 94156 | 0.322273673 |
| XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 vs NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 | NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | 4072 | 253054 | 10012 | 0.406711946 |
| XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 vs NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 | XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 | NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 | 28397 | 253054 | 81936 | 0.346575376 |
| XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 vs XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 | XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150 | 4930 | 253054 | 11470 | 0.429816914 |
| XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 vs XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 | XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 | XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150 | 253054 | 253054 | 253054 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your discrete `x` and `y` axis mappings to a `factor` you can control the order in which they appear.

```r
sample_order <- c(
"NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150",
"NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150",
"XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_IgG_p150",
"NC_rep1_nogel_wash10_p150",
"NC_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150",
"XL_rep2_nogel_wash10_p150" )

best_peak %>%
  separate(`Peak Comparison`, into = c("peak1", "peak2"), sep = " vs ") %>%
  mutate(
   label = paste(percent(Rate, accuracy = 1),
                 comma(Intersection.Value, accuracy = 1), sep = "\n"),
   across(c(peak1,peak2),
          ~factor(., levels = sample_order))
    ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(peak1, peak2, fill = Rate)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(aes(label = label), size = 1.50, color = "gray80", lineheight = 0.7) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```